# What it do you call a business or a craft a family has been doing for generations

Tags: single-word-requests

What is that word used to refer to a business or craft a family has been doing for generations? Many families for example have been carpenters for 5 generations. What is carpentry to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may sound rather silly or straightforward but for the 5<sup>th</sup> generation carpenters, Carpentry is their ***[family business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_business)***.

From Wikipedia,

> A family business is a commercial organization in which decision-making is ***influenced by multiple generations of a family—related by blood or marriage—who are closely identified with the firm through leadership or ownership***. Owner-manager entrepreneurial firms are not considered to be family businesses because they lack the multigenerational dimension and family influence that create the unique dynamics and relationships of family businesses

For instance, [WalMart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walmart) is a ***family business***, run by the [Walton Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walton_family)

Comment: I know it is a bit late but Thank you! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you are skilled carpenters you could be described as 'artisans.'

"A worker in a skilled trade, especially one that involves making things by hand[1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/artisan)."

Carpentry, in your instance, could be described as an 'artisanal family trade.'

A family trade has a long history of use, suggesting that several generations have been involved / worked as *'X*.'[2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=family%20trade&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfamily%20trade%3B%2Cc0)